# Provide another example in which a metal appliance can become energized besides the hot wire coming in contact with the metal frame of the appliance

Tags: metal, neutral, ground

A dangerous situation where no ground path is available is typically cited as the hot wire coming in contact with the metal frame of an appliance and thus energizing it and potentially shocking or electrocuting the next person that touches it.  Can you give me another example of how a metal appliance can become energized?  What if the neutral wire becomes disconnected at the main panel, the hot wire is not really touching the metal still so not sure this example would qualify.  Are there any other legit ones?

Comment: That is the main one, probably the only simple case, where a hot touches the frame.  The main reason the hot, hot, neutral were banned was when the neutral acting as ground became loose/disconnected there was no safety protection for people.  These days you even need to add GFCI protection for extra safety

Comment: Your locality may (or may not) have a bearing on the validity of answers. Good idea to reveal it!

Comment: You're absolutely right, should have mentioned this was in a US based system (Florida).  I will make sure to include location next time, thanks.

Comment: This stack's policies don't really support contrived or hypothetical questions which are at best [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) or at worst a rationalization to do something bad. What is the conclusion/outcome you are trying to reach, or better, what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Just educating myself.  When I don't know an answer to something and can't find it through online research, I ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if the neutral wire becomes disconnected at the main panel, the hot wire is not really touching the metal still so not sure this example would qualify.

It absolutely qualifies. The hot wire ***really is*** is "touching" the neutral (and the unsafe bonded to neutral frame/casing) through the circuit that would be operated by hot-to-neutral voltage (such as the motor in a dryer, or the light bulb in an oven) and will energize it quite well enough to kill a person if the neutral is broken.

Seriously, fix the unsafe NEMA-10 devices you still have hanging around your home with a separate ground wire and a NEMA 14 receptacle, or 4-wire connection properly wired.

Comment: Wow this just hit me when you explained that it still IS touching the metal through the existing neutral bonded to the frame (even if the neutral becomes disconnected at the panel).  Don't know why that didn't register with me before.  This is what I was missing, now the separate ground path in all cases really makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: @Fred  I imagine the designers of NEMA 10 did not think of it either at first.

Answer (score 2):

There have been cases where guitarists in particular have succumbed to a similar situation.

The three-pin plugs (UK style) have the earth on the pin furthest away from the strain relief, where the cable exits the plug. If the cable gets pulled enough times, it becomes detached from its post, and can wander about inside the plug. So far, no problem, and no clues as to a potential problem. The appliance continues to work, as the live and neutral are still both attached. So, no sign of a problem yet.

That can occur when the earth wire eventually finds its way to touching the live post inside the plug. Still no sign of a problem, as no fuse will blow. And the appliance will continue to work happily. BUT, by now, the chassis, or metal parts of said object - in those cases, the guitar and its strings - will become live. Still no actual problem - the circuit is not completed.

Until - the guitarist happens to touch a radiator, or more likely, a mic, which has its metal cover connected to earth, usually in another amp, connected properly. It's at that point that the circuit is completed, with the current passing from one hand to the other. Travelling through the victim's heart en route, sometimes with fatal consequences. Another twist is that the electricity will cause muscles to contract, thus making it difficult to impossible to let go of the source. This has happened on stage to several guitarists causing their demise at gigs.

Hence the use these days of RCDs, which are (or should be) used at all venues, and have the capability to measure the difference between the current going in and out, and tripping quickly enough to save lives - and also, in my case, equipment.

Comment: This is an interesting and nasty problem! I wonder if more modern UK plugs have a barrier built-in between the leads' connections so the wires can't wander about inside the plug case?

Comment: @Triplefault - all modern UK plugs are moulded, have been for ages. However, I'm still using quite a few of the old style screw -it- yourself ones. I used to be H&S in schools ~40 yrs ago, and there were so many old plugs to check, and I spent some time re-wiring those with the above problem. Frightening.

Answer (score 1):

Supply neutral becomes disconnected on a TN-C-S supply.  That's one where the supplier provides a grounded (earthed) neutral, not a separate ground wire.

In particular, it's a problem where the broken neutral is before the point where the installation's ground is connected to the neutral.

Even where an earth rod has been installed, it's unlikely to have a low enough resistance to keep the "touch voltage" down, and everything metal in the installation becomes live.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain, some electrical systems are connected so the neutral-ground bond is in the utility line, not in the house's electrical panel. According to John Ward, author of the video ["TN-C-S Danger - Broken PEN Conductor (Combined Earth & Neutral)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE) , if the neutral line before the neutral-ground bond breaks, it would be possible for the case to be energized *without any faults* in the house's or case's wiring:

[image: TNCS NG Break, power can still flow]
(from John Ward's video, red X and arrow added by me)

The Neutral line breaks before the Neutral Ground bond, leaving the ground system floating. Power can still flow from line to neutral to ground to case, and if someone completes the case to earth ground connection, electrocution can happen. Mr. Ward reports that the RCD (GFCI to the folks across the pond) would not protect in such a situation. Makes sense, since the power is still travelling balanced through the protection device.

I could imagine the same problem happening in North American wiring if the house does not have a suitable ground line coming out of the panel to earth ground, and the power company neutral also breaks:

[image: similar break in North American wiring]

Since power is still balanced on the line & neutral wires, GFCI probably would not catch the problem.

Comment: Yeah, John Ward's example is exactly how 3-prong dryers and ranges kill people.